# Passed reference getting a value of subclass

Tags: c#, subclass, pass-by-reference

Consider the following code that I have written for my own education.  I have a main method, a static method and two classes - hold and subhold.  Subhold extends hold.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        hold h = new hold();
        h.aa = 88;
        Console.WriteLine("In main " + h.aa);
        thismethod(h);
        Console.WriteLine("In main2 " + h.aa);
        Console.WriteLine("In main3 " + h.ss);  //ERROR

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

   static void thismethod (hold h) {
       Console.WriteLine("In thismdethod " + h.aa);

       h.aa += 1;
       Console.WriteLine("In thismdethod1 " + h.aa);
       h = null;
       subhold subhold = new subhold();

       subhold.aa = 8888;
       subhold.ss = 22222;

       h = subhold;

    }


}

class hold
{
    public int aa { get; set; }

}

class subhold : hold
{
    public int ss { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to access h.ss.  Right now I have no access to it.  How can I access `h.ss` from the main method?

Comment: Couple of things, first Base class can't access properties/members of child class. Second read about [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: `h` is a `hold`, not a `subhold`. It doesn't have an `ss` property.

Comment: I also tried using the `ref` such as `thismethod (ref h)` with `static void thidmethod (ref hold h)`

Comment: If you pass it with `ref`, then `thismethod` will actually change the instance of `h` to a `subhold`, but it's still declared as `hold` in Main. So you can do that and cast it: `((subhold)h).ss`

Comment: @Habib That's a good article.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thank you.  I read your comment at least 30 times. So in `thismethod` I created a chicken `subhold` and set it to animal `hold`  In the main method, I can have the chicken back if animal is indeed a chicken.  Is that about right?

Comment: @Zuzlx I have expanded on my comment in an answer. I think you understand though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base class does not (and more importantly should not) know anything about derived class
 properties. Different derived classes could have a different set of added properties. 
 Making the base class aware of this would counteract important principles of object 
 oriented design

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        subhold h = new subhold();
        h.aa = 88;
        Console.WriteLine("In main " + h.aa);
        thismethod(h);
        Console.WriteLine("In main2 " + h.aa);
        Console.WriteLine("In main3 " + h.ss);  //no ERROR

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `h` by reference, then `thismethod` will change Main's `h` to point to an instance of `subhold`.

The variable `h` in `Main` is still **declared** as `hold`, though. So you need to cast it to `subhold` in order to access `ss`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    hold h = new hold();
    h.aa = 88;
    Console.WriteLine("In main " + h.aa);
    thismethod(ref h);
    Console.WriteLine("In main2 " + h.aa);
    Console.WriteLine("In main3 " + ((subhold)h).ss);   // casted, no error.

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void thismethod (ref hold h) {                   // passing by reference
   Console.WriteLine("In thismdethod " + h.aa);

   h.aa += 1;
   Console.WriteLine("In thismdethod1 " + h.aa);
   h = null;
   subhold subhold = new subhold();

   subhold.aa = 8888;
   subhold.ss = 22222;

   h = subhold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again.  Good stuff!